# How to keep the space characters for read.table in R?

Tags: r, whitespace, delimiter, read.table

I have a tab-delimited file that some columns comes with 1 or more space characters, i.e., the whitespaces except the delimiters (tab), which I need to keep. For example the file could be generated with bash shell command:

```
echo -e " \t*\t  \t*\t*\t  \t*" > test.tab
```

then I read the file in R

```
f=read.table("test.tab", header=FALSE, sep="\t", strip.white=FALSE, na.strings='');
f
V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7
1 NA  * NA  *  * NA  *
s=as.character(f)
s
[1] "NA" "*"  "NA" "*"  "*"  "NA" "*"
```

I actually wanted s to be "spacestarspacespacestarstarspacestar", not NA in the string.

I also tried comma-delimited format, but got the same results.

```
echo -e " ,*,  ,*,*,  ,*" > test1.csv # or
echo -e "' ',*,'  ',*,*,  ,*" > test2.csv
f=read.table("test1.csv", header=FALSE, sep=",", strip.white=FALSE, na.strings='');
f
V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7
1 NA  * NA  *  * NA  *
as.character(f)
```

[1] "NA" "*"  "NA" "*"  "*"  "NA" "*"
f=read.table("test2.csv", header=FALSE, sep=",", strip.white=FALSE, na.strings='');
as.character(f)
"NA" "*"  "NA" "*"  "*"  "NA" "*"

How to get the space characters? TIA

Comment: I am not seeing the same results. The `-e` is getting sent to the file "test.tab". And it's also not clear why you think the result should have tab-characters in it since you specified that tabs were separators. Separators should not remain after input to R dataframes.

Comment: I edited my question. what I wanted to see s to be "spacestarspacespacestarstarspacestar"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because it's not reading in those columns as characters

`read.table('test.tab', sep = '\t', colClasses = 'character')`

will read in the spaces correctly.

Comment: This is what I need. Thanks!